# Core Data Entity Screen

Tags: ios, coredata

Создал 2 Entity. У Entity Post указана ссылка на класс .Post.

Вообще-то с этой entity я создавал класс PhotoDataPost.

Поэтому вопросы: 
1) как Entity понимает, к какому классу она привязана и привязывается ли она вообще? 
2) зачем в строке с entity Post указан какой-то класс .Post?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Да, она привязывается к классу указанному в поле class.

2) Xcode предполагает, что класс называется так же как и entity и пытается вам помочь автозаполнением.

Зачем еще нужен class: когда вы создали свою модель в .xcdatamodeld, вы можете сгенерировать (или обновить) все классы указанные в модели. Для этого выберите File -> New -> File -> Core Data -> NSManagedObjectSubclass, xcode спросит для каких файлов из модели надо генерировать классы, и после этого сгенерирует нужные вам файлы, с именами которые вы указали в этом самом поле class. При этом, если вы не поставили точку в начале названия, то в сгенерированном классе будет строка `@objc(Post)` для использования класса в обжс.